# getting two ipaddress from the same FQDN

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of IP addresses from several servers defined in `server.txt`.

Each server has 2 IP addresses and 2 FQDN.

Example:

```powershell
servername (Production lan):server1 IPaddress:147.111.111.16
servername (backup lan):server1-bck IPaddress:10.0.4.12
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content server.txt
$server2 = "$servers-bck"
$zai = ""
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  $zai = $zai + $server + "`t" +
    ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server) | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString}) +
    "`t" +
    ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server2) | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString}) +
    "`n"
}
$zai > IP-address.csv
```

Unfortunately only the IP for `Production lan` is correct. The IP for `backup lan` only shows the IP of the last server in server.txt.  I assume the problem is in: `"foreach { echo $._IPAddressToString"`. I don't know how to fix it.

Any idea or advice will be helpful.

Comment: This is just a personal opinion, but I think using the **foreach** alias of **ForEach-Object** should be avoided, to distinguish it from the **foreach** control structure. They have similar purposes, but fundamental differences that make it important not to confuse them with each other. You can use **%** as an abbreviation for **ForEach-Object**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume that

```
$server2="$servers-bck"
```

would append `-bck` to the name of each element in the array `$servers`. That is not the case. Instead, the array is expanded by joining its elements using the [output field separator](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/effective-powershell-item-15-using-the-output-field-separator-ofs/), so that `-bck` ends up after the last array element:

```
PS C:\> $a = 'a', 'b', 'c'
PS C:\> $a
a
b
c
PS C:\> "$a-bck"
a b c-bck
```

To get the backup server for each server from your list you need to append `-bck` *inside* the loop:

```
...([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server-bck"))...
```

As a side-note, you shouldn't build CSVs manually. Let PowerShell do that for you:

```
$servers | % {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Name'       = $_
    'Production' = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_) | select -Expand IPAddressToString) -join ' '
    'Backup'     = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$_-bck") | select -Expand IPAddressToString) -join ' '
  }
} | Export-Csv 'IP-address.csv' -NoType -Delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: this help solve my issue. its really helpfull. im new to powershell thus i always endup making this mistake.